# Do ions also form special electron configurations? (just as Copper and Chromium do)

Tags: theoretical-chemistry, electronic-configuration

Do ions also form special electron configurations? (just as Copper and Chromium do)

I know that because copper has 1 electron in its s-orbital (highest) because it wants to have a full d-orbital (d^10)

But do ions also act this way?

Comment: What do you mean by special?

Comment: that it will remove an electron from the s orbital to the d-orbital to have a stable half filled s-orbital and stable fully filled d-orbital

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [NIST database](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/ionEnergy.html) for electronic configurations for atoms and ions in the gas phase. If you play around a bit, you will find that yes, some ionizations will not follow the expected trends from the *aufbau* principle. For example, search for rhenium and compare the configurations between $\ce{Re^{11+}}$ and $\ce{Re^{17+}}$, and you'll see some of them are unexpected (and rather hard to explain). Osmium shows an anomaly going from $\ce{Os^{+}}$ to $\ce{Os^{2+}}$. There are other elements with ions containing *aufbau* anomalies, but I can't remember many from the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, the electrons will change orbitals to fill shells (even if it is an ion). This is why the transition elements can have more than one ion.